# Missing partitions after restore windows 7 form restoring point

Tags: windows, restore

sorry if this is not the right place where I have to add my question, but I am in a big trouble. Today after installing a program, my windows 7 starts to throw an error, and I decided to restore it with back date. And I did I restarted it and pressed f8 then system restore I choose a point one day back and everything went well until I realized that there are two missing partitions E: and F: I've opened acronis disc director and I saw just one partition and is not located I cant see it in My computer section at all. Is there a way to restore again from the same point and to have my partitions? Thanks in advance. and sorry if my English is not so good.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you lost your partitions after a recovery. But you can try if you can see your partitions with this tool: http://www.partitionwizard.com/download.html
Install and run it.